# jQuery select click event of button with particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamically added buttons on my page inside a table. Two buttons, with classes "`editbuttonclass`" and "`deletebuttonclass`".

I am using this jQuery selection to run on my button click event, it runs on both buttons though, how can I run separate functions depending on the button class?

**jQuery**

```
$('#table').on('click',"button", function(e){})
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$('#table').on('click',"button .editbuttonclass", function(e){})
```

Comment: remove space between button and class `"button.editbuttonclass"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `class` belongs to the button, so don't give a space:

```
$('#table').on('click',"button.editbuttonclass", function(e){})
//----------------------------^
```

When you give a space, it becomes a descendant selector, which selects the elements that are children to the tag.

Answer (score 3):

Use `button.classname`, `button .editbuttonclass` looks for an element with class `editbuttonclass` within a `button` element - [descendant selector](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

```
$('#table').on('click',"button.editbuttonclass", function(e){})
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
 $('#table').on('click',"button.editbuttonclass", function(e){})
```

Remove the white space between button and button class.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

                    var trHTML = "";

                    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        trHTML += '<tr><td>' + "item.name" + '</td><td>' + "item.id" + '</td><td>' + "item.price" +
                                    '</td><td>' + '<button id="item.id" class="btn deletebuttonclass">Delete</button></td><td>' + '<button id="item.id" class="btn editbuttonclass">Edit</button>'
                        '</td></tr>';

                        $('#table').append(trHTML);
                    }


                    $('#table').on('click', "button.editbuttonclass", function (e) {

                        alert('do edit function')
                    })

                    $('#table').on('click', "button.deletebuttonclass", function (e) {

                        alert('do delete function')
                    })
        });


    </script>



    <body>
     <table id="table" border=1 align="center" height="150" width="200">
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="100">Product Name</th>
                <th width="100">Price</th>
                <th width="100">Id</th>
                <th width="100">Delete</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>


        </tbody>
    </table>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: for the nth time :)... i dont see any difference from this answer and the answers 10mins ago